# X implements X — what does it mean?

Tags: typescript

I've noticed that it's perfectly legal to write

```
class X implements X {
  ...
}
```

but I'm unclear on the semantics.  What does it actually do?  I want it to mean "X is the name of a class, but we will use it as an interface", but I notice you can write this:

```
class X  {
...
}

interface Y extends X {
}
```

Which means that `implements X` isn't adding that.  So what does it add?

Comment: Try checking https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38834625/whats-the-difference-between-extends-and-implements-in-typescript as it seems to touch this topic a bit.

Comment: @Moira — not only is a duplicate, it was inspired by the same example, Inversify's sample `Ninja implements Ninja`.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't accomplish anything. It tells the compiler to check that class X implements everything in class X, which of course will always be true.