# Exclude definition conflicts Typescript

Tags: typescript

Below is the implementation of `Exclude` floating around on various blogs ( One [Reference](https://bloggie.io/@_ChristineOo/typescript-understanding-how-omit-pick-exclude))

`type Exclude<T, U> = T extends U ? never : T;` According to Typescript blog, it constructs a new type by excluding some properties from the union type. Perfect, I get it.

Let's detail this out.

If `T` extends `U` it returns never. Fair enough. Extends means that we are inheriting all properties. ( [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38834997/1096194) - https://stackoverflow.com/a/38834997/1096194)

Confusion is that if ternary condition returns false, Shouldn't it return `T - U` instead of T as we may want to return only `T - U` properties in case `T` is not an extension of `U`.

Let's take an example #1

```
U = "name", T = "id" | "name";
```

If I understand correctly, `T` extends `U` is false in this case as `T` did not inherit all properties from `U`. So, we should return `T-U` i.e. "id" which is the desired output of exclude operator.

Let's take another example #2

```
U = "name", T = "id" | "email"
```

In this case too, ternary fails as the `T` does not extend or inherits anything from `U`. So it should return `T - U` i.e. `id | email` happens to be equal to `T` in this case.

So, what is the correct definition anyway i.e. `T extends U? never: T` or `T extends U? never: T - U`?

Comment: I'm not sure your question is clear. Are you asking about [distributivity of conditionals over unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types)? The first paragraph in the documentation should explain why the original definition works.

Comment: This answers my question. Was not aware of "distributivity of conditionals over unions?"

Answer (score 1):

As @artcorpse said in the comments, conditional types are resolved like this:

```
with T = A | B | C;

T extends U ? X : Y
```

means

```
(A extends U ? X : Y) | (B extends U ? X : Y) | (C extends U ? X : Y)
```

So in your example:

```
U = "name";
T = "id" | "name";

T extends U ? X : Y
=>
("id" extends "name" ? never | "id") | ("name" extends "name" ? never | "id")
=>
"id" | never
=>
"id"
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types

"In instantiations of a distributive conditional type T extends U ? X : Y, references to T within the conditional type are resolved to individual constituents of the union type (i.e. T refers to the individual constituents after the conditional type is distributed over the union type)."