# Accessing protected members from class implementation in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, abstract-class, implementation, protected, abstraction

I'm getting this error when trying to implement a protected member in TypeScript.
Is there a way to avoid it? Or am I doing something the wrong way here?

It seems that TypeScript does not recognize implementations of a class as its subclass, like it does for extensions.

```
Class 'MyClassImpl' incorrectly implements class 'MyClass'.
Did you mean to extend 'MyClass' and inherit its members as a subclass?
Property 'myMember' is protected but type 'MyClassImpl' is not a class derived from 'MyClass'.
```

```
abstract class MyClass {
  protected abstract myMember: boolean
}

class MyClassImpl implements MyClass {
  /**
   * Class 'MyClassImpl' incorrectly implements class 'MyClass'.
   * Did you mean to extend 'MyClass' and inherit its members as a subclass?
   * Property 'myMember' is protected but type 'MyClassImpl' is not a class derived from 'MyClass'.
   */
  protected myMember: boolean
  constructor() {
    this.myMember = true
  }
}

class MyClassExt extends MyClass {
  /**
   * This way it just works fine, but I wanted to implement a class, not extend it
   */
  protected myMember: boolean
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.myMember = true
  }
}
```

I tried to implement a protected member of an abstract class, and I expected it to be available for the implementation class.
I expected that TypeScript would recognize an `implements` class as a subclass, just like it does for `extends` classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This behaviour is a bit surprising](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51692) but it is [working as intended](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42660#issuecomment-774165244).

The key phrase is "`implements` checks assignability" – the presence of a `protected`/`private` field means that the classes will be [compared nominally](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#when-and-why-are-classes-nominal) rather than structurally. Overriding the `abstract` field requires a different declaration, so it is a different field even though it has the same name.

It's consistent if a bit unhelpful in this case, but as you've discovered there is an easy enough workaround – [using `extends` instead of `implements`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38834997/21146235), so that the `protected` field is inherited.

Comment: I have to say I'm not fully pleased with that workaround, since its sounds like a semantical mistake for me (I'm implementing a class, not extending it).
Also, it will require the use of the `super()` call on the constructor and maybe other side effects we might not be aware yet.
The solution that I chose to use on my project (also not semantically perfect) was to mark the member as `public readonly` instead of `protected`...

Comment: I was considering open an issue on TypeScript repository, but I don't want to get a crappy answer like [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37447#issuecomment-600839794)

Comment: I think there's arguably a path here to treat `abstract protected` members specially since there's no JS footprint to complicate things, but I imagine the implementation might be obtuse. The `implements` keyword is, of course, misleadingly named when nominal typing gets involved.

Comment: TS has its gaps when considering OOP paradigma, and that's comprehensible since JS is focused on being functional instead of object-oriented. This issue would be avoided if TS had simply implemented the `interface` concept like all the other programming languages.
I've just accepted that I won't have a 100% satisfying solution for this case, life goes on...
Thanks for the help!