# TypeScript class implements class with private functions

Tags: typescript, implements

I was exploring the possibility of having a class implementing a class in TypeScript.

Hence, I wrote the following code [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20f()%20%7B%20console.log(%22f%22)%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20g()%20%7B%20console.log(%22G%22)%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20B%20implements%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20g()%20%7B%20console.log(%22g%22)%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A):

```
class A {
    private f() { console.log("f"); }
    public g() { console.log("G"); }
}

class B implements A {
    public g() { console.log("g"); }
}
```

And I got the error: `Class 'B' incorrectly implements class 'A' --- property 'f' is missing in type 'B'` coupled with a suggestion that I actually meant `extends`.

So I tried to make a private field called `f` (`public` didn't work as it detects they have different access modifiers) [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20f()%20%7B%20console.log(%22f%22)%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20g()%20%7B%20console.log(%22G%22)%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20B%20implements%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20f()%20%7B%20console.log(%22F%22)%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20g()%20%7B%20console.log(%22g%22)%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A)

Now I get the error: `Class 'B' incorrectly implements class 'A'. Types have separate declarations of a private property 'f'`; this leaves me very confused:

- why do private members even matter - if I implement the same algorithm using different data structures, will I have to declare something named the same just for the sake of type checking?
- why do I get the error when implementing `f` as a private function?

I wouldn't do this in practice, but I am curious about why TS works like this.

Thanks!

Comment: @Igor I don't want that :)

I am exploring the way `implements` behaves on classes.

Comment: Ok. Does this shed any light on your question? [Extending vs. implementing a pure abstract class in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35990799/1260204).

Comment: @Igor No, as I already implement all of the functions in the class I'm implementing (see second Playground link)

Comment: You may also be interested in [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/471)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The issue [Microsoft/TypeScript#18499](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18499) discusses why private members are required when determining compatibility.  The reason is: *class private members are **visible** to other instances of the same class*.

One [remark](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18499#issuecomment-329842291) by @RyanCavanaugh is particularly relevant and illuminating:

> Allowing the private fields to be missing would be an enormous problem, not some trivial soundness issue.
>     
> Consider this code:
>
> `class Identity {
>   private id: string = "secret agent";
>   public sameAs(other: Identity) {
>     return this.id.toLowerCase() === other.id.toLowerCase();
>   }
> }
>     
> class MockIdentity implements Identity {
>   public sameAs(other: Identity) { return false; }
> }`
>
>
> `MockIdentity` is a public-compatible version of `Identity` but attempting to use it as one will crash in `sameAs` when a non-mocked copy interacts with a mocked copy.

Just to be clear, here's where it would fail:

```
const identity = new Identity();
const mockIdentity = new MockIdentity();
identity.sameAs(mockIdentity); // boom!
```

So, there are good reasons why you can't do it.

---

As a workaround, you can pull out just the public properties of a class with a mapped type like this:

```
type PublicPart<T> = {[K in keyof T]: T[K]}
```

And then you can have `B` implement not `A` but `PublicPart<A>`:

```
class A {
    private f() { console.log("f"); }
    public g() { console.log("G"); }
}

// works    
class B implements PublicPart<A> {
    public g() { console.log("g"); }
}
```

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: I think the example is a bit dishonest, `other.id` wouldn't have been accessible in the `sameAs` method, right?

Comment: If you're suggesting that the `Identity` class as written is invalid, [you can test it yourself](https://tsplay.dev/3NDA8m) and see that it is indeed valid.  An instance of a class with a private property can access that property on other instances of the same class.  That's how TS's `private` works and also how JS's upcoming `#` private property syntax works (you can test it yourself in Chrome, I think).  So rest assured that the examples here are in good faith.  Cheers!

Comment: "An instance of a class with a private property can access that property on other instances of the same class" – interesting, I didn't know that. Thanks

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, that interpretation of "private" by the typescript spec strikes me as quite odd.

Comment: This *private* access is the same in most programming languages. However, ECMAScript (JavaScript) is introducing private class fields (with the `#` prefix) which are actually inaccessible by instances of the same class. A world first? \[[1](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields)\] \[[2](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-private-methods)\]

Comment: @LarsGyrupBrinkNielsen `#`-private fields will act the same way as `private` does in terms of accessibility: an instance of class `Foo` will indeed be able to access private members of other instances of class `Foo`.  If your runtime environment supports private fields (I think Chrome does) you can check for yourself [here](https://jsbin.com/xozuyi/edit?js,console).  TypeScript's implementation of it also behaves like this; see [here](https://tsplay.dev/WYJrbw).

Answer (score 6):

The current solution with out-of-the-box support from Typescript is simply

```
class A {
    private f() { console.log("f"); }
    public g() { console.log("G"); }
}

class B implements Pick<A, keyof A> {
    public g() { console.log("g"); }
}
```

Explanation: `keyof A` only returns public properties (and methods) of `A`, and `Pick` will then down trim `A` to only its public properties and their respective type.

Comment: Yes, this should be a utility type!

Answer (score 2):

In this case it is not possible with the current typescript specifications. There is a [tracked issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/471) for this but it is closed.

[Suggestion: Permit an implementing class to ignore private methods of the implementee class](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/471).

---

See also [Extending vs. implementing a pure abstract class in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35990799.)

Comment: Thanks! It seems like TS compiler doesn't allow doing this at the moment. I feel that in this scenario implementing a class should be fully disabled.

Comment: @RaduSzasz - correct. Looking at the GitHub issue you are not the first to have come across it and I doubt you will be the last. Hopefully they will address it one way or another (*make it possible or create a better error message*).

Answer (score 1):

This is fundamentally due to the fact the visibility of private members are scoped to the type, and not the instance. Meaning that all objects of the type T have access to the privates of other objects of type T.

This is not a problem in nominatively typed languages as all instances of T inherits the implementation of T, but since typescript is structurally typed, it mean that we can not assume that all instances that fulfill T have the implementation of the class that declares type T.

This means that privately scoped members have to be a part of the public contract of the type, otherwise an object of the structural type T could call a non-existing private member of another object with the same structural type.

Being forced to have privates being a part of a public type contract is bad, and could have been avoided by scoping privates to the instance and not the type.