# Trying to use a class as an interface, but TS requires private constructor properties

Tags: typescript

Given class `MyClass`, why are private constructor fields `required` when implementing an object with the type `MyClass`?

They're `private`, so shouldn't they be ignored when implementing an object that conforms to the class?

**Tiny Example**

```js
class MyClass {
  constructor(
    private privateString: string,
  ) {}

  method1(): number {
    return 1;
  }
  method2(): number {
    return 2;
  }
}

/*
Property 'privateString' is missing in type '{ method1: () => number; method2: () => number; }' 
but required in type 'MyClass'.ts(2741)
*/
const Stub: MyClass = {
  method1: () => 1,
  method2: () => 2,
};

/*
Type '{ privateString: string; method1: () => number; method2: () => number; }' 
  is not assignable to type 'MyClass'.
Property 'privateString' is private in type 'MyClass' 
  but not in type '{ privateString: string; method1: () => number; method2: () => number; }'.ts(2322)
*/
const Stub: MyClass = {
  privateString: '',
  method1: () => 1,
  method2: () => 2,
};
```

Tested on `Typescript 4.4.3`

Comment: [This behavior is intentional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#private-and-protected-members-in-classes). Are you looking for speculation on why they designed it that way?

Comment: That's so strange, I guess _private_ members, are not truely private to that class then, if anything implementing the class requires them. 

Yes I was wondering how to avoid this issue when mocking a class with a POJO

Comment: Class private members are visible to other instances of the same class, as [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48953930/2887218) to the linked question demonstrates, and as you can see in [this example](https://tsplay.dev/WYYbdW).