# Why Typescript allows implements abstract class?

Tags: typescript, class, interface, extends, implements

I'd [reading](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#abstract-classes) about typescript's `class` and `abstract class` and I did find something very interesting.

`Typescript allows us to implement classes`.

I even created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ktelyg) project to test it.

Anyway, I already found the general differences [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10839131/implements-vs-extends-when-to-use-whats-the-difference), and what is its behavior in typescript [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35990538/extending-vs-implementing-a-pure-abstract-class-in-typescript/48291679#48291679).

[I'm aware that it can be used to create mock for tests.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48291679/6061376)

Why typescript allows it, if in other very popular languages (`Java`, `C#`,...) it is 'forbidden'? Is There any other important application of this feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before you asked this question I didn't think about, but after I read your question it didn't let me go because I didn't know an answer as well, so I simply asked a typescript lang (core) dev via twitter and I got a reply so I will leave it here.

[image]

[Twitter Source](https://twitter.com/SeaRyanC/status/1085278257899917312)

expressed in a simple way: "if it works it ain't stupid" and they didn't disallow it because it works